# How does using an RS232 splitter affect the data transfer speed?

Tags: serial, rs232, pcie

I am converting digital data into an analog signal through the RS232 PCIE card I added to my PC. I have a desire to collect data from up 8 different RS232 connections and I am looking into using an RS232 splitter to collect the 8 different signals into one port (hopefully still getting 8 COM ports though).
These were the products I was looking at, but if I can't collect data as close to real time as possible, then I will need to rethink my strategy.

- [https://www.amazon.com/Industrial-Splitter-Adapter-Sharing-Capture/dp/B07B631G26?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B631G26)
- https://www.dtechelectronics.com/dtech-oem-odm-audio-and-video-transmission-distribution-1x4-port-1-in-4-out-rs232-serial-splitter_p286.html

Does this make data transfer slower (8 times slower since there are 8 ports through 1)?

A work around I'm considering is adding more RS232 cards to the other two PCIE slots I have (but one would have to accept 4 ports, like this card [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004WKTBHW?ref_=cm_sw_r_cp_ud_dp_MKXG8GQQF8KT56VK5CWJ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004WKTBHW))

My code has my RS232 ports set to 115200 baud and this is strictly a RS232 to RS232 connection, no USB involved.

Comment: We used to use things like [this](https://www.ti.com/product/TL16C554A), back in the day. You'd need two. And an MCU+code to operate them. But it looks as though you are shopping on Amazon. So I'm probably of no help.

Comment: "Does this make data transfer slower (8 times slower since there are 8 ports through 1)?" - Yes. What is your objection to using a handful of USB-RS232 adapters?

Comment: It is unknown how the expanders work. The marketing material suggests all kinds of ways, but fails to mention how the port switching between devices is done or is this just a logical AND between all data ports. So it is unlikely you can simultaneously talk to 8 devices in any other way than having 8 COM ports on your PC.

Comment: @jonk I will keep that chip in mind since I may need to get intricate to get the results I want. Shopping on Amazon is just my first attempt at a solution. I am always open to shopping on Digikey or Mouser. :)

Comment: @brhans I received advice that USB would be slower than RS232 in my scenario. I am interfacing Unity (the digital) to an Arduino (Teensy 3.2 using the DAC) (the analog) and using the RS232 line to communicate between them. I was under the impression that USB using "packets?" would add extra lag/latency.

Comment: @Justme definitely another key factor would be if there are [Port Names](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.portname?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) (COM1-COM8) that I can talk/reference to so I can call them in C# on Unity.

Comment: You can change USB RS232 latency settings in your windows device manager, typically down to about 1mSec. That's a little more than 11 bytes @ 115200 baud rate. If your argument is that you don't want to have to fiddle with those settings, then have you considered that your proposed PCIe RS232 cards will have FIFO buffers in them which are likely to be at least somewhere in the 16-64 byte range, and that these are equally as likely to cause you to experience latency as USB 'packetization'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That splitter takes 1 input and outputs to 8 inputs, and each output gets the same data as the input. I doubt it does traffic control through RTS and CTS, but if it did only one device could talk at at time. That would be 115.2kbaud/8. No matter what serial device you get, you can't talk faster than roughly 115.2kbaud so splitting RS232 doesn't get you more bandwidth and only one device can talk at a time.  In addition, the code would have to be modified to talk to multiple devices, and you would have to also give the devices the ability to not talk at the same time (probably by checking the hardware lines, assuming that the splitter actually passes those down the line).

If you have more than one port, (like 8 ports) then all 8 ports can talk at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation that it would be slower and using 8 ports would be the best solution. From what I read on the splitters I was looking at, only three of lines (Rx, Tx, GND) are used, so there would be no RTS/CTS control for those 8 lines.

Comment: If you don't have RTS/CTS then you have to depend on software to tell when the line is being used, which would prove difficult if using more than one device on a port.

Comment: I definitely am depending on software (Unity) right now to call/open/close the lines/COM ports. I've been using [Serial.open()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.open?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) and [Serial.close()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.close?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) when communicating. But all of that through one port... That is why I was hoping, digitally, more COM port would show even though it is the one physical port.